# If I know the mean, median, mode, and so on how do I determine the standard PDF that most fits

Tags: statistics

I have been playing a game and it drops currency with a drop rate that has an expected value of $1/750$ and nothing else. I was able to keep track of 3000 drops and times between them. I can then find the Mean, Median, Mode, Skewness and so on. How do I find the PDF that governs the times between drops from this data? My calculated Standard deviation was 7500 the skewness about 18 and the hypothetical distribution is like none I've previously seen.

This is a SRS of my data set, I didn't have time to compile all of it nicely,

> 1875,893,267,2003,946,393,136,1215,255,124,593,984,2685,772,1112,1448,636,916,299,821,939,68,678,881,794,797,10,133,284,2367,830,610,209,1482,896,378,2246,6,19,746,2295,19,769,2760,87,967,24,2008,1106,1094,660,1272,90,2919,927,223,691,177,170,2930,998,610,451,1246,53,538,126,21,1801,2023,358,296,170,454,296,2466,172,170,1222,173,847,1123,1553,682,364,338,475,608,3390,422,217,667,1107,170,804,500,31,1331,590,1411,424,22,417,51,804,1001,2321,255,260,863,89,876,1109,124,251,223,494,1669,606,251,193,166,540,157,1089,304,2046,555,952,223,308,1150,1974,389,433,817,1213,208,2387,166,856,132,386,437,1753,607,2317,220,48,376,154,1293,96,363,335,153,767,656,1938,1072,444,761,204,333,893,221,315,318,38,58,285,497,546,718,639,53,165,620,297,434,1380,1371,78,138,512,1231,76,697,654,837,1394,11,2348,2844,746,655,751,80,762,305,22,1573,99,316,779,366,163,114,386,722,779,507,137,20,288,157,395,899,111,304,51,400,520,1787,225,794,627,658,2805,980,1752,713,496,107,571,1149,972,1510,303,110,452,199,2096,823,320,847,265,3150,332,936,753,2034,47,144,301,723,224,30,398,1838,2161,254,1455,2161,636,1331,833,745,255,488,122,717,405,171,333,589,1206,434,572,1983,969,657,503,362,145,65,1084,94,1889,249,802,333,1132,582,1070,431,200,587,335,1394,794,465,100,1866,183,749,685,710,73,1153,1014,261,1139,6,460,969,389,403,1168,267,1245,893,431,77,540,269,496,1061,741,1583,560,535,1391,174,62,177,217,794,424,1131,228,2,26,286,102,43,2189,3271,722,650,759,1010,96,115,396,537,938,2135,597,2284,460,388,768,489,793,60,2448,803,545,61,1217

this is what the data looks like plotted. any pointers?
[image: sorted data]

histogram
[image: Histogram]

To clarify I want to know if there is a way to see if my stats meet the stats of any normal PDF's.

Comment: The "and so on" is tricky. If you really know all moments you know the pdf exactly (at least theoretically) if your data range is bounded,  see the "moment problem". If you only know a few moments plus median, all you can do is try out some well known pdfs. But then again there is no point arguing just by matching moments that your data is represented by some named distribution.  You should, once that you have an estimate,  try to understand the connection between your data and the distribution.

Comment: Also, I would argue that if you find a named pdf that matches all moments you have while coming from a family of pdf with only two parameters that would be better than finding a match from say a family with 5 parameters. This is Ockham kind of handwaving though and the last part of my previous comment still holds

Comment: Finally, you shouldn't talk about "normal pdfs" as "normal" has an established meaning in statistics as referring to the Gaussian distribution

Comment: Skewness doesn't equal two but you gave me the pointers I need thank you.

Comment: Revising my earlier Comment, now deleted: Putting the recently provided sample of 371 observations into Minitab, I find good fit to exponential with mean 729. Slightly better fit with Gamma(shape=1.11, scale=655). Glad you're on a useful track now. Sample estimates of skewness and kurtosis are notoriously variable, so don't worry too much about matching theoretical skewness                2.

Comment: Thanks, Your'e awesome I can now do things like calculate the probability of getting a card within a certain number of drops and due to the skewness i can refresh the game if it takes to long and expect a better drop rate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Comment on a kind of answer that is sometimes useful
in statistical practice. It is not a 'real' Answer, because I
don't think there is one.  There is no reason that the process from which you're collecting
data corresponds to *any* distribution that has been 'named' by someone.

Perhaps you have access to Minitab statistical software. It has a procedure, for nonnegative data only, which tries matching given data to more than a dozen well-known
families of distributions. (I understand that R also has such a
procedure in one of its many libraries, but I have never used it.)

In Minitab the procedure is in the **Quality** menu under *Individual distribution ID.*  As a demo, I generated a random sample of 3000 observations
from the exponential distribution with population mean 10. Here are some
descriptive statistics for my simulated data.

```
           Total
 Variable  Count    Mean   StDev  Minimum     Q1  Median      Q3  Maximum
 x          3000  10.198  10.352    0.001  2.984   7.117  13.889   93.187


 Variable  Skewness  Kurtosis
 x             2.06      6.17
```

You can check on Wilipedia `exponential distribution` that $Exp(\mu = 10)$ has mean 10, SD 10, skewness 2, and kurtosis 6. So my sample
is a reasonable one.

The identification procedure indicated good fits
to exponential, gamma, and Weibull distribution families. This
is reasonable because the exponential family is a sub-family of
more extensive gamma and Weibull families.

Fits to the gamma and Weibull families were a little better than
to exponential because these more extensive families have more
parameters and could, by chance, better fit a few of the quirks
of my particular sample of 3000.

(There were also
'pretty good' matches to a couple of other strongly right-skewed
distribution families that have no relationship to exponential.)

In summary, your idea of trying to match 3000 observations to
some well-known distribution is an interesting one, and one that
arises frequently in statistical practice. (Frequently enough, anyhow, that  the commercially-minded people at Minitab thought it worthwhile to make a procedure for it.) But the question 
does not necessarily have a clear-cut and satisfactory answer.
Even in examples like mine where the answer is *known* there
can be multiple suggested 'fits.' (And even more so, with
smaller samples.)

*Note:* The approach to try matching sample moments to population moments
is interesting from a theoretical point of view, but I have not
seen it used in practice to identify a distribution family. (However,
'method of moments' estimation uses this approach.)

---

**Addendum:** Following on @Ian's Comment, here is one page of four probability plots for various families of distributions, among many tested by Minitab. ('AD' = Anderson-Darling.)

[image]

Comment: Relevant: once you specify a metric of "goodness of fit" and a domain of admissible distributions, the uniqueness problem usually goes away in theory. The real difficulty is when your domain of admissible distributions is "too big", whether that is because you are drawing from a parametrized family of distributions with many parameters, or because you are drawing from a *nonparametrized* family of distributions.

Comment: Apparently Minitab uses Anderson-Darling goodness-of-fit as metric, and it shows probability plots with 'confidence bands' between which most observations should lie. Appending one page of graphs from MTB output.